# Why did community delete my answers without giving me a few days warning?

Tags: discussion, support

It is my fault that I didn't read the [rules][1] carefully about sharing links. I didn't know that I was supposed to fully disclose my association with the company I am working for (eg. So my colleague wrote this article about practice tips/made this video lesson on...) and so I left my answers as they are. When I read my email from community stating moderation, I logged into my account, and saw that my answers were removed. My answers were removed four hours later after the email was sent.

I don't know if this seems unfair that they did not to give me a few days warning - I honestly didn't know that I had to disclose my affiliation with the company, nor do I even know what astroturfing meant until I Now I cannot edit those answers, nor can I even answer any question.

Anyway, I just want to know why.

Answer (score 5):

You were given an acquitted warning in an upvoted comment to [one of your now deleted answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16723/how-can-i-increase-my-note-reading-and-finger-strength/59084#59084) which you flagged twice as rude or abusive:

> Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must
>   disclose your affiliation in the answer**, otherwise, your answer may
>   be flagged as spam. If you are not affiliated with the site, I
>   recommend you say so to prevent this. Please read [How to not be a
>   spammer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).
>   Additionally, please don't use link shortener websites.

After the second flag was received, a little more digging was done and every single one of your answers referenced the same site or had them appear in a video. All but one of the posts were then marked spam and that one had the link edited out because it didn't influence the answer. This site is not for trying to market a site or a product. It's ok to use sources from a site you are affiliated with, but you must disclose it.

Comment: that I understand, as Community had emailed me these rules clearly. But why did they send me a warning in email, then later on, delete my three answers in less than 24 hours? I didn't even get to edit the other three answers by disclosing and removing links.

Comment: @MusicLover24 Spam is taken very seriously on SE sites. The fact is that you were warned by users of the site that have the ability to flag your posts as spam if needed. You were given two full days to resolve this and not only did you not, but you flagged the comment twice which put more eyes on this which agreed that you're posts were spam like and seeing similar issues in your other posts, actions were taken.

Comment: Ok I see what you and SE mean about spamming. Was I really given two full days, including my sleeping hours?  And where does it say on SE that they can remove the answers in two full days? As a new user, I didn't  know that when I registered, until someone pointed it out and I had a different meaning in mind when someone mentioned spam (eg posting a link not related to the topic. So my next questions are:  Is there anyway I can still can answer questions, or am I completely blocked from answering forever? I made one big mistake, and it's harsh on someone who had no clue before.

Comment: @MusicLover24 the block is temporary. Asking good quality questions will help show that you're ready to start contributing to answers again.

Comment: Thank you Dom! Much appreciated. Sorry about the spamming.